# SVN - store-passwords=no

Tags: linux, svn, passwords

i got a question concerning linux and svn.
I run ubuntu on a virutal box and actually I am not used to linux yet.
For researches I am connected to a svn-server, which I update often.

At the beginning I was asked if my password should be stored unecrypted. I choose to store the password but now I want to change it. I already googled a lot, but this didn't help me. It was often said to change to /etc/subversion/config but this directory doesn't exist, oly /subversion/ exists, but this folder is empty.

Can anybody tell me how I can set, that I always have to enter my password as soon as I do a svn up or svn commit? Please give a detailled description, because I am still used to Windows ;)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `$HOME/.subversion/auth` folder, where `$HOME` is your home directory (i.e. `/home/<username>`). You should find a like like `$HOME/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/<some_hex_string>` which contains the stored credentials for your repository. Delete that file.

(To reset **all** your svn settings, you can just delete the `$HOME/.subversion` folder.)